# Laravel QB Collection

Tags: laravel

I have a collection that returns the correct users however using this substring_index function does not alphabetize the entire collection by the user's name as desired. Is there a better method I need to use here.

```
{{ dd(App\User::whereHas('roles', function($q) {
       $q->where('name', '=', 'rprm');
   })->orderByRaw('substring_index(trim("name"), " ", -1)')->pluck('name', 'id')) }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your query.

```
{{ dd(App\User::whereHas('roles', function($q) {
       $q->where('name', '=', 'rprm');
   })->orderByRaw('substring_index(TRIM(name), " ", 1)')->pluck('name', 'id'))
}}
```

I assume you want to use MySQL's **TRIM** function.

Comment: That would work if I was doing names such as Bob Smith and it was alphabetizing by Bob however I need it to alphabetize by the last name.

Comment: @user3732216 You can do that replacing 1 with -1.